# Effective method of error handling a function

Tags: python-3.x, exception, error-handling

Example error handling function:

```
def read_file():
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fd:
            x = fd.read()
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        return(e)
    return(x)
```

I would call the function like so:

```
file = read_file("test.txt")
if file:
    #do something
```

is there a more efficient/effective way to handle errors than using return multiple times?

Comment: what would happen in your main code in case the error was returned? would you make another check whether `file` is an error or a string? I would say `raise e` instead of `return` and then also handle the function call. After all, you wouldn't want to proceed if an error was raised

Comment: Could you provide an example as an answer please?

Comment: It is a little hard without more context of your code or purpose because right now as it seems I would just give up the function. The `try/except` block independently would do the job

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange to catch `e` and then return it; why would a user of your function want the error to be returned instead of raised? Returning an error doesn't handle it, it just passes responsibility to the caller to handle the error. Letting the error be raised is a more natural way to make the caller responsible for handling it. So it makes sense not to catch the error at all:

```py
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fd:
        return fd.read()
```

For your desired use-case where you want to write `if file:` to test whether the file existed, your `read_file` function could catch the error and return `None`, so that your `if` condition will be falsey:

```py
def read_file(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fd:
            return fd.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

However, this means that if the caller isn't aware that the function might return `None`, you'll get an error from using `None` where the file data was expected, instead of a `FileNotFoundError`, and it will be harder to identify the problem in your code.

If you do intend for your function to be called with a filename that might not exist, naming the function something like `read_file_if_exists` might be a better way to make clear that calling this function with a non-existent filename isn't considered an error.